# Using PhoneGap Cleaver in iOS to override method

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am using PhoneGap 2.3 - Cleaver for iOS.

How can I override shouldStartLoadWithRequest, webViewDidStartLoad, webViewDidFinishLoad function?

If I add "viewController.webView.delegate = self" to viewDidLoad, the functions above can be called but the PhoneGap API cannot be invoked.

Thanks.

MyViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
    viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    //viewController.webView.delegate = self;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:landingURL]];
    [viewController.webView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
}
```

MyViewController.h:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't override shouldStartLoadWithRequest because there is where they manage the javascript urls that call the native functions.

Or at least copy their code from the CDVViewController into your view controller and add the things you need.

example from phonegap 2.9.1

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL* url = [request URL];

    /*
     * Execute any commands queued with cordova.exec() on the JS side.
     * The part of the URL after gap:// is irrelevant.
     */
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"gap"]) {
        [_commandQueue fetchCommandsFromJs];
        return NO;
    }

    /*
     * If a URL is being loaded that's a file/http/https URL, just load it internally
     */
    else if ([url isFileURL]) {
        return YES;
    }

    /*
     *    If we loaded the HTML from a string, we let the app handle it
     */
    else if (self.loadFromString == YES) {
        self.loadFromString = NO;
        return YES;
    }

    /*
     * all tel: scheme urls we let the UIWebview handle it using the default behavior
     */
    else if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
        return YES;
    }

    /*
     * all about: scheme urls are not handled
     */
    else if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"about"]) {
        return NO;
    }

    /*
     * all data: scheme urls are handled
     */
    else if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
        return YES;
    }

    /*
     * Handle all other types of urls (tel:, sms:), and requests to load a url in the main webview.
     */
    else {
        if ([self.whitelist schemeIsAllowed:[url scheme]]) {
            return [self.whitelist URLIsAllowed:url];
        } else {
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
            } else { // handle any custom schemes to plugins
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];
            }
        }

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

the `if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"gap"])` manages phonegap calls

BTW, you shouldn't use phonegap 2.3, you need at least 2.5 to pass apple store guidelines added in may, versions previous to 2.5 used the UDID and it's forbidden by apple